# Error in running a simple c program in dev c++

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
  int f,c;
  printf("enter the value of celsius in integer (the value of f will be shown in integer neglecting the float value)");
  scanf("%d,&c");
  f=((9*c)/5)+32;
  printf("f=%d,&f");
  getch();
  }
```

When i am going to compile and run this program in my window 7 then in compiler it is showing the string to enter the digit but when i am entering a digit to finding out its f then it is giving an error "celcius.exe has stopped working" and after that it is showing "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Window will close the program and notify you when a solution will available." How it will be handle in dev c++. Please help me to sorting it out.I am new with c. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d,&c");
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&c);
```

and

```
printf("f=%d,&f);
```

to

```
printf("f=%d",f);
```

### Side note:

Never use `main()` instead use `int main()` and better to use `int main(void)` and do not forget to add `return 0` before closing braces of `main`.
In Dev C++ no need to use `getchar()`. It will cause to double press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&c);
f=((9*c)/5)+32;
printf("f=%d",f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as per following
    `scanf("%d,&c");`  to `scanf("%d",&c);`
    `printf("f=%d,&f);`  to `printf("f=%d",f);`

However your program will give wrong results most of the time. You should declare `f` and `c` as float so that `f=((9*c)/5)+32;` will be evaluated as float division. Now with your code it will be evaluated as integer division. integer division `10/3` will be evaluated to `3` not `3.33`.

Rewriting your code

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<conio.h>
  main() 
  {
     float f,c;
     printf("\nEnter Celcius -");
     scanf("\n%f",&c);
     f=((9*c)/5)+32;
     printf("\nf=%f",f);
     getch();
     return 0;
  }
```